# Can the Funambol C++ API be used for Symbian Series 40 development? 

Tags: c++, series-40, funambol

Can I use the [Funambol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funambol#Funambol_project) API for Symbian [Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) development using C++, as the Series 40 SDK is not available for C++?

Comment: Series 40 is not a Symbian platform. I've edited tags accordingly.

Comment: @laalto: Didn't know that. Learnt something new :)

Comment: is it true that we can not program in c++ for s40 devices ??

Comment: As a third party developer you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell - not with C/C++, as the SDK is Java ME based and apparently does not include [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). But I believe Funambol also supports Java ME - so you may not need to use C/C++.